# By convention of python, can subclass access parent's variables whose names start with a single leading underscore "_"?

Tags: python, oop

In python, by convention, a leading underscore in a variable's name (e.g., `_var`) is to indicate it is for internal use.
However, should this "internal" variable still be revisable by subclasses (by convention)?

In other words, is `_var` private or protected?

Comment: You will still be able to access those attributes from the sub class, most IDE's will highlight with a warning if you do it, and it is generally considered bad practice to modify them, but it can be done.

Comment: _nod_. "Not a public interface, if your reliance on it causes something to break you get to keep both pieces" applies for both reading and writing.

Comment: Just found this: "Python doesn't have any mechanism that effectively restricts access to any instance variable or method. Python prescribes a convention of prefixing the name of the variable/method with single or double underscore to emulate the behaviour of protected and private access specifiers." from https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/private-and-protected-access-modifiers-in-python#:~:text=Python%20prescribes%20a%20convention%20of,from%20outside%20the%20class%20environment.

Comment: Basically, it comes down to documentation. You can *document* `_var` as being suitable for the author of a subclass to use or not, depending on what exactly the class uses it for.

Answer (score 1):

[Pep 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has some useful bits.

TL;DR :: There's no true *private* or *protected* modifiers in Python. You can think of attributes as being *non-public* which is by convention, but not strictly enforced. Attributes can be buried a little deeper by using a double underscore (ex.: `__name`) at the beginning, but this has some issues(/is controversial?). (See notes.)

From PEP *ocho*:

> Use one leading underscore only for non-public methods and instance variables.
> **To avoid name clashes with subclasses, use two leading underscores to invoke Python's name mangling rules. Python mangles these names with the class name: if class Foo has an attribute named __a, it cannot be accessed by Foo.__a. (An insistent user could still gain access by calling Foo._Foo__a.) Generally, double leading underscores should be used only to avoid name conflicts with attributes in classes designed to be subclassed.**
> Note: there is some controversy about the use of __names (see below).

And then, further on this:

> If your class is intended to be subclassed, and you have attributes that you do not want subclasses to use, consider naming them with double leading underscores and no trailing underscores. This invokes Python's name mangling algorithm, where the name of the class is mangled into the attribute name. This helps avoid attribute name collisions should subclasses inadvertently contain attributes with the same name.

> Note 1: Note that only the simple class name is used in the mangled name, so if a subclass chooses both the same class name and attribute name, you can still get name collisions.

> Note 2: Name mangling can make certain uses, such as debugging and **getattr**(), less convenient. However the name mangling algorithm is well documented and easy to perform manually.

> Note 3: Not everyone likes name mangling. Try to balance the need to avoid accidental name clashes with potential use by advanced callers.

Answer (score 0):

single underscore means "protected" by convention

According to
[https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/private-and-protected-access-modifiers-in-python#:~:text=Python%20prescribes%20a%20convention%20of,from%20outside%20the%20class%20environment](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/private-and-protected-access-modifiers-in-python#:%7E:text=Python%20prescribes%20a%20convention%20of,from%20outside%20the%20class%20environment)

"Python prescribes a convention of prefixing the name of the variable/method with single or double underscore to emulate the behaviour of protected and private access specifiers."

Comment: That's not the complete story. The association of `_`-prefixed names and protected attributes is something people outside of Python use to try to understand the convention, not something used by the Python documentation itself. PEP-8 only says that the convention applies to "non-public" variables, without making any distinction between protected and private.

Comment: Are you suggesting that each project should have its own convention for this?

Comment: I'm suggesting that `_var` is not part of the external interface of an instance of a class. Whether you choose to bless its use by a subclass should be made on a class-by-class basis. It's easiest to implement if you assume it is off-limits unless otherwise documented.

Answer (score 0):

Categories of attributes, as defined by the [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#designing-for-inheritance):

> Public attributes are those that you expect unrelated clients of your class to use, with your commitment to avoid backwards incompatible changes. Non-public attributes are those that are not intended to be used by third parties; you make no guarantees that non-public attributes won’t change or even be removed.
>
> Another category of attributes are those that are part of the “subclass API” (often called “protected” in other languages). Some classes are designed to be inherited from, either to extend or modify aspects of the class’s behavior. When designing such a class, take care to make explicit decisions about which attributes are public, which are part of the subclass API, and which are truly only to be used by your base class.

And guidelines to use them:

> Public attributes should have no leading underscores.

> If your class is intended to be subclassed, and you have attributes that you do not want subclasses to use, consider naming them with double leading underscores and no trailing underscores.

This implies to me that attributes intended to be used only by subclasses (the "subclass API") should have a single leading underscore.